# How to delete a row using trigger in oraclesql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using 2 tables, orders and order_items. I am trying to create a trigger that when I delete an order_id from orders table a row with the same order_id will be deleted in order_items table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_order_items
AFTER DELETE ON orders
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM order_items WHERE order_items.order_id = orders.order_id;
END;
```

Could someone explain to me, why the above code does not work and how should it be written?

Comment: Consider an ON DELETE CASCADE foreign key instead.

Comment: @jarlh I thought of that as well and it does not make sense to me why should I use a trigger, but this is for homework where I am required to do so

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, then please take note that your instincts are correct - this is NOT a proper job for a trigger, and the FK constraint is the correct solution to the actual business problem. I hate it when instructors do things like this.  Use this assignment to learn what you can about how triggers work, but do not take it as a good example of how to solve the proposed business problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You referenced `ORDERS.ORDER_ID` in a wrong manner; should have been `:old.order_id`. Also, should be row-level trigger as you can't reference `:new` or `:old` values in statement-level triggers.

```
create or replace trigger orders_order_items
  after delete on orders
  for each row                                        -- this
begin
    delete from order_items where order_items.order_id = :old.order_id;
                                                         ----
                                                      -- this
end;
/
```

Comment: I get an error saying "NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers" when I try this.

Comment: So true; missing `for each row` as well. Fixed; have a look, please.